# Selenium python Chrome - actions class does not send_keys

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

There exists a government page that is password protected; my code logs me in fine. Then I am attempting to populate the following input with code below:

```
<td ><script type='text/javascript'>$('.inputs').keydown(function (e) {if (e.keyCode == 39) 
{$(this).parent('td').next().find('.inputs').focus();}else if(event.keyCode == 13)
 {event.preventDefault();$(this).parent('td').next().find('.inputs').focus();return false;}
else if (e.keyCode == 37){$(this).parent('td').prev().find('.inputs').focus();}});</script>
<input type="Text" ID="95413" Name="WellName_95413" value="" class="bind_WellName inputs"
onkeyup="changeValue(event)" onchange="changeValue(event)"  
style="width:100%;margin: 0px 2px 0px 2px; height: 25px;" ></td>
```

Code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/km/Documents/chromedriver245/chromedriver.exe')
well_name = driver.find_element_by_id('95413')
actions = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(well_name)
actions.click()
actions.send_keys('test well name')
actions.perform()
```

Nothing happens - the field does not have the text populated and no error is shown on the console, it just says:

```
C:\Python37>python.exe eForm_dev.py

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:56091/devtools/browser/771d733c-e1a1-4bbc-b43b-ac8a4f39a122

C:\Python37>
```

I have tried other approaches that didn't work either:

- `well_name.send_keys()` by itself
- `well_name.click()` then `well_name.send_keys()`
- `well_name.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)` then `well_name.send_keys()`

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on adding

```
time.sleep(3)
```

before

```
actions = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)
etc.
```

And it works. Why?